# Copy Class From Another Project and Removing the Connections in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, reference

I have copied the contents of `SignView.h` and `SignView.m` from an existing project.

However, the **connections were included** in the following attributes:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *signHereLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clearBtn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *doneBtn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SignatureView *signView;
@property(strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

- (IBAction)clearBtnAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)doneBtnAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backBtnAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)gestureAction:(id)sender;
```

Every time I check the `UIView` in the connection, it shows that it is connected to **the other project `xib` file where the `UIView` class came from** (which is weird).

If I remove the connections, it affects the other project instead of the current project I'm working on.

*I'm pretty sure I created the file, copied the contents only and not the entire file, so the file is not a reference (supposed to be), but a real file.*

**Question**

So, how do I remove the connection inside the contents of my copied `SignView.h` file. And how do I connect `SignView.h` in my current project properly?

Comment: The connections are stored in the XIB or Storyboard. Did you copy it? Did you add the XIB or Storyboard of the other project to this project?

Comment: No, I did not copy the `xib` file. I just copied the class, but it points to the `xib` file in the other project.

Comment: Does restarting Xcode solve the problem?

Comment: No, not really. I think it has something to do with how XCode uses an `id` reference inside the `xib`, which is probably used by the `interface` attributes. An `attribute` connects to the same reference `id` if the `interface` name is the same. So, after copying and pasting the contents of the file, you need to remove those connections first from the other project before connecting it again to the new `xib` file of the new project... Or something like that (I'm still working on it).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the file you added are referenced from the source try to copy them when you add them to your project by :-

[image]

**Edit**

> Another thing you can do is change the name of your IBActions and IBOutlets like nameLabel to nameLabelMyVc(according to your requirement) and then remove the reference from storyboard or nib whatever you're using and connect the fresh outlets that you've renamed.

Comment: I did copy the contents of the file, and I did not copy the file itself. That's what's weird. I did that and the attributes still pertains to the other project.

Comment: Changing the attribute name and action does not remove the connections. If I remove the reference from the `xib`, since the class is connected to the **other project** `xib`, the one that is going to be affected is the other project.

Comment: why dont you copy the xib into your project? I'm sure if you copy the xib and select the "Copy items if needed checkbox" and remove the connection from the copied xib then connect it to the new outlets it will work.